# Using bupaR, how can I combine the counts and times from the process and performance maps into one map?

Tags: r, process-management

I'm aware that you can combine a combination of edges and nodes from the two as shown [here](https://www.bupar.net/processmaps.html#combining_different_profiles).

However, I'm trying to create something similar that displays both the counts and times on both the edges and nodes if possible like the following at the bottom. With something like this, one wouldn't have to constantly compare the process/performance maps side by side to see which counts match up with which times.

[Example Combined Process & Performance Map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IEX2F.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just discovered the "sec_nodes" and "sec_edges" arguments which allow you display both a time and count which is good enough, thought I'm not sure if it's possible to display a third type and edge statistic.

```
patients %>% process_map(performance(mean, "hours"), 
type_nodes = performance(median, "hours"), 
sec_nodes = frequency("relative"),
type_edges = performance(median, "hours"), 
sec_edges = frequency("relative"))
```